# SSRS - On what basis should I decide to choose Dataset Filter or Dataset Parameter?

Tags: reporting-services, ssrs-2012

For a shared dataset, that needs to be used as part of a cascading parameter; the logic can be implemented using Filter or Parameter.

For example - If there are 3 parameters - 1. Start Date (date); 2. End Date (date); 3. Policy (multivalue text) - and the task is to cascade the start/end date values to populate the Policy parameter.

We can implement this by using **dataset filter** - by having the Policy param dataset to include 3 columns: Startdate, enddate and policy and then filter the parameter to show only those policies that belong to the selected dates.

And also the same can be implemented using **dataset parameter** by having the Policy param dataset accept start/end date as parameters.

What is the best practice approach please?

Comment: If I recall correctly, filters are applied on the SSRS server side and parameters are applied in the database so I would always recommend parameters as they will reduce the recordset before it arrived at the SSRS server

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As you already you, we can use Dataset parameter and Dataset Filterto filter out required Data.

As far as my knowledge goes, it is always better to use dataset parameter. Reason: it will filter out data coming from database i.e on Report you will have let's say 100 Records rather than 1200.

Now if you use Dataset Filter you will have in your report 1200 records but you are filtering on top of your 1200 records in Report to just show 100.

That means fetching data and then using dataset filter will cost you more time and memory than dataset parameter.

Now when is dataset parameter more useful, just last week I had requirement to filter records (field: "created on date") by months.
This requirement was not possible using dataset parameter because I use Fetchxml as query and in fetchxml I cannot just add parameter on month. In this case unfortunately I had to use Dataset Filter. Reason: I could use expression to tweak filter.